# Загрузка ЦП 100% kworker при использовании второго монитора в Linux - видеокарта NVIDIA

Tags: linux, загрузка, экран, процессор, видеокарта

**При подключении второго экрана к компьютеру, в линуксе происходит загрузка ЦП на 100% процессом kworker** (оба ядра, либо иногда одно из ядер, нагружены полностью; при этом kworker совсем не юзает оперативу). *При загрузке в линукс с уже подключенным вторым монитором происходит то же самое!*
При работе только с одним монитором в линуксе такого не происходит.
**Это безобразие происходило на девайсах с разной конфигурацией**: и **на ПК** *(Intel Celeron E3300 2.5 ГГц 2 ядра x64, 4 ГБ ОЗУ, дискретное видео NVIDIA GeForce GT 520)*, и **на нетбуке** *(Intel Atom Z520 1.33 ГГц 1 ядро 2 потока x86, 2 ГБ ОЗУ, встроенное видео Intel GMA poulsbo)*; **причем это происходило на разных дистрибутивах**: Lubuntu 16.04, Zorin OS Lite 12, Devuan ASCII, Debian 9. 
В каждом случае два монитора были подключены к одной видеокарте.
Подозреваю, проблема кроется в софте, который обеспечивает вывод на экраны? Или это <s>фича</s> баг только Debian-based дистрибутивов?
Как избавиться от бесполезной 100%-ной загрузки процессора при использовании двух мониторов?
*p.s. прошу не посылать в гугл, я пришел именно оттуда*
**UPD! Выяснено, что на нетбуке с картой Intel GMA 500 тормоза были не из-за kworker, а из-за того, что девайс сам слишком стар и слаб, чтобы тянуть такое суммарное разрешение экранов. Так что остается подозревать только вещи, связанные с NVIDIA.**

Comment: `kworker` — это поток ядра... обычно высокая нагрузка свидетельствует о баге в ядре, неисправном оборудовании или какой-то чудной конфигурации...  если в гугл уже ходил, то должен был заметить, что основным инструментом исследования, какая именно подсистема ядра виновата является `perf`, так что вывод в студию...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, записал 10 секунд активности на всех ядрах:
`# perf record -g -a sleep 10`
Получил [такой вот вывод](https://pastebin.com/Ux1UZErK). Не понимаю, что за `__i2c_transfer` и `drm_get_edid`, но, кажется, kworker жрет ЦП, когда обнаруживает подключение второго монитора (`nouveau_connector_detect` и `nouveau_connector_hotplug`).  
Получается, во всем виноват драйвер видюхи nouveau и лучше поставить проприетарный от NVIDIA? Но тогда почему на системе с другой видеокартой (Intel GMA 500) такая же проблема? Не могу понять

Comment: да всё так... нуво пока обеспечивает не лучшую производительность, хотя по моему опыту обычно работает стабильно... так что, если нет религиозных проблем, а также с устареванием версий драйвера, то на nvidia лучше использовать проприетарный блоб... также можно попробовать обновить/откатить/собрать самостоятельно ядро... также, если есть желание и возможность, можно написать разработчикам нуво... на второй машине лучше посмотреть отдельно... пока я бы сказал, что это странное удивительное совпадение...